# Can mysql handle a dataset of 50gb?

Tags: mysql, database

Can mysql handle a dataset of 50gb (only text) efficiently ? If not, what database technologies should I use ?

thanks

Comment: You can use `Apache Cassandra` if you want scalability. That's the reason it was designed. (http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/)

Comment: Are you referring to table sizes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, I would say **yes**. MySQL can handle 50GB of data, efficiently.

If you are looking for a few examples, Facebook moved to [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra_(database)) only after it was storing over 7 Terabytes of inbox data.

- Source: [Lakshman, Malik: Cassandra - A Decentralized Structured Storage System](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/ladis2009/papers/lakshman-ladis2009.pdf).

Wikipedia also [handles hundreds of Gigabytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:FAQ/Technical#How_big_is_the_database.3F) of text data in MySQL.

Comment: If you're going to cite FB + inbox data, you should finish by recalling that the reason they moved to Cassandra was that doing this in MySQL was so painful. :)

Comment: @jbellis: True. My point was that they migrated to Cassandra much later than 50Gb. I modified my answer to make this a bit more clear The source I cited explains the details.

Answer (score 4):

Any backend that uses b-trees (like all the popular ones for MySQL) get dramatically slower when the index doesn't fit in RAM anymore.  Depending on your query needs, Cassandra might be a good fit, or Lucandra (Lucene + Cassandra) -- http://blog.sematext.com/2010/02/09/lucandra-a-cassandra-based-lucene-backend/